# nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send('Yo');
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.send("Yo");
    },1000);
});
```

It looks like "send" ends the request. How can I get this to write `Yo` on the screen and then 1 second later (sort of like long polling I guess) write the other `Yo` to get `YoYo`? Is there some other method other than send?

Answer (score 2):

Use `res.write` to generate output in pieces and then complete the response with `res.end`.

Comment: That would still send the entire response in one shot though, I think what@K2xL is trying to do is send messages separately whenever results become available, so sockets would be the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.
Once you send a response, the client-server connection will be closed.

Look into sockets (particularly [socket.io](http://socket.io/)) in order to keep a connection open and send multiple messages on it.

Answer (score 0):

the thing with node.js is that it relies on an ***asynchronous*** "style". so if you introduce something like a "wait" function, ***you'll lose all the benefits of the asynchronous way of execution***.

I believe you can achieve something similar to what you want by:

1. (*asynchronous way*) including a function that prints the second "Yo" as a callback to
   the first function (or)
2. (*classic wait(synchronous)* ) introduce a 'big' loop before presenting the second 'Yo'.

for example:

```
for(i=0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with JQuery+JSON. send the response and then update what ever you need with JQuery and JSON.

This is a good [tutorial](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/write-a-todo-list-with-express-and-mongodb/) of expressjs, including DB stuff (mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the result as a single block try

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('Yo');
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.end("Yo");
    },1000);
});
```

or something like

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    var str = 'yo';
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.end(str + 'yo');
    },1000);
});
```